# What is this caterpillar I've found?

Tags: caterpillar

[image][image][image]

I found this caterpillar in my garden. Does anyone know what it is? It's in Michigan.

Comment: It looks like it is of the Noctuidae family. If I found one in the UK I would be inclined to say that it was a caterpillar of the Dot Moth (feeds on low growing plants, trees, and shrubs) or the Copper Underwing, which feeds on oak, birch, sallow, various other trees and shrubs.

Comment: Welcome Liv! Thanks for those excellent pictures! Can you give us a bit more information please, since caterpillar identification can be tough. What type of plant is that? Are the caterpillars only on that plant or also others? Are they eating holes in the leaves? Is this the first time you've had them? Are there a lot? The best way to give us more information is to add it directly into the question by pressing the gray "edit" under the text. We look forward to helping you!